# Why java.sql.PreparedStatement interface don't appear when searched with getInterfaces()

Tags: java, jdbc, javaagents

I am trying to instrument a class that implements the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` interface. I have tried it using following code in the transform method, but it doesn't even go through such a class. But i am running my agent with a main class which contain `executeQuery` method.

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer)
            throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;

        ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();

        try {
            CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));

            if (!ctClass.isInterface()) {
                CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
                Class[] interfaces =className.getClass().getInterfaces();
                for (Class c : interfaces) {
                    System.out.println(c.getName());
                    if (c.getName().equals("java.sql.PreparedStatement")) {
                        System.out.println(c.getName());
                        for (CtMethod method : methods) {
                            if (method.getName().equals("executeQuery")) {
                                this.testSignature(method);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
                byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
                ctClass.detach();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
```

I tried it using `classBeingRedefined.getInterfaces()` as well, then it returns a nullPointerException at certain classes because classBeingRedefined turns null.

**Edit 1**
Output of c.getName() is a long list of following class names.

```
    java.lang.CharSequence
    java.io.Serializable
    java.lang.Comparable
```

**Edit 2**

```
String fullyQualifiedClassName = className.replace('/','.');
                Class currentClass = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName);
                Class[] interfaces = currentClass.getInterfaces();
```

Comment: Please add the output of System.out.printing(c.getName())

Comment: Are you looking for `com.sql.PreparedStatement` (title & question) or `java.sql.PreparedStatement` (code)?

Comment: Um looking for classes that implements the java.sql.PreparedStatement, so um trying to check the interfaces of each class that loads while my server is running.

Answer (score 3):

Reason is you are looking interfaces for `String` class since variable **`className`** is actually a String.

Either you can pass `Class className` in the method or use

```
Class c = Class.forName("Fully qualified class Name");
c.getInterfaces();
```

Comment: Earlier i tried with classBeingRedefined.getInterfaces(); But in that case, sometimes it returns nullPointerException because classBeingRedefined variable turns null.

Comment: use class name not instance

Comment: When i use the following code as the above answer (given in edit2), 
i get following two exceptions. `java.lang.ClassCircularityError` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. First one is the frequent one, second occured just once or twice. At the end it stopped executing with following line. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name:`